# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.' on Button Save

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I don't know what's wrong with my code, when I add data then save, I get this error.
FYI I use Visual Basic language.

[1][This is the error of my code]
[1][https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxSie.png]

```
Private Sub TsSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsSave.Click
    If aksi = "insert" Then
        TBL_BukuTableAdapter.InsertQuery(txtJudulBuku.Text, txtPengarang.Text, txtPenerbit.Text, txtTahunTerbit.Text, txtkategori.Text)
        TsRefresh.Text = "Refresh"
    Else
        TBL_BukuTableAdapter.UpdateQuery(txtJudulBuku.Text, txtPengarang.Text, txtPenerbit.Text, txtTahunTerbit.Text, txtkategori.Text, txtIdbuku.Text)
    End If
    Me.TBL_BukuTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UASDataSet.TBL_Buku)

    TsAdd.Enabled = True
    TsDelete.Enabled = True
    TsSearch.Enabled = True
    aksi = "update"
End Sub
```

This is my full code

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim aksi As String = "update"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'UASDataSet.TBL_Buku' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TBL_BukuTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UASDataSet.TBL_Buku)
        txtIdbuku.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub TsAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsAdd.Click
        TsAdd.Enabled = False
        TsDelete.Enabled = False
        TsSearch.Enabled = False
        TsRefresh.Text = "Cancel"
        aksi = "insert"
        TBLBukuBindingSource.AddNew()
        txtIdbuku.Text = TBL_BukuTableAdapter.IdBukuBaru()
        txtJudulBuku.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TsSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsSave.Click
        If aksi = "insert" Then
            TBL_BukuTableAdapter.InsertQuery(txtJudulBuku.Text, txtPengarang.Text, txtPenerbit.Text, txtTahunTerbit.Text, txtkategori.Text)
            TsRefresh.Text = "Refresh"
        Else
            TBL_BukuTableAdapter.UpdateQuery(txtJudulBuku.Text, txtPengarang.Text, txtPenerbit.Text, txtTahunTerbit.Text, txtkategori.Text, txtIdbuku.Text)
        End If
        Me.TBL_BukuTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UASDataSet.TBL_Buku)

        TsAdd.Enabled = True
        TsDelete.Enabled = True
        TsSearch.Enabled = True
        aksi = "update"
    End Sub

    Private Sub TsDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsDelete.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Delete Data?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            TBL_BukuTableAdapter.DeleteQuery(txtIdbuku.Text)
            Me.TBL_BukuTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UASDataSet.TBL_Buku)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TsRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsRefresh.Click
        TsRefresh.Text = "Refresh"
        Me.TBL_BukuTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UASDataSet.TBL_Buku)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TsSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TsSearch.Click
        If TxtKeyword.Text <> "" Then
            TBL_BukuTableAdapter.FillByJudulBuku(UASDataSet.TBL_Buku, TxtKeyword.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: I just add the `Id_buku` to this code.
But it still don't work
[this is the code][2]
[2][https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3RRQ.png]

`If aksi = "insert" Then TBL_BukuTableAdapter.InsertQuery(txtid_buku.text,txtJudulBuku.Text, txtPengarang.Text, txtPenerbit.Text, txtTahunTerbit.Text, txtkategori.Text)`

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient is for ms sql server, not for mysql, therefore I changed the database product tag.

Comment: what does `TBL_BukuTableAdapter.InsertQuery` do? And if you view the details of the  exception, you should find the querytext that has thrown the exception. Please at that also to the question

Comment: I see, thankyou for changing the tag... @Shadow

Comment: @derpirscher , `TBL_BukuTableAdapter.InsertQuery` to add some new table sir.
but i don't really know about your next statement ,sir. Sorry because i'm just starting to learn about this vb.

Comment: We need the code of the insertquery, since that's where the error is

Comment: @ViryaKho Well we all would have guessed that. But that method is where the error is happening. If `TBL_BukuTableAdapter` is something of your own code: Show it. If it's some well known external library, at least say what it is and how you configured it. You are probalby using it wrong. And try to get hold of the query text that is really executed. Because that's where the error is. This query is probably generated inside `TBL_BukuTableAdapter.InsertQuery` but without seen any code, nobody can help you

Comment: here you are the code of the inseertquery... https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jFam.png
is it okay if i share the link of the picture? because i cant put the picture again ..

This is the insertquery code.
`INSERT INTO TBL_Buku
             (Judul_buku, Pengarang, Penerbit, Tahun_terbit, Kategori, id_buku)
VALUES (@Judul_buku,@Pengarang,@Penerbit,@Tahun_terbit,@Kategori,)`

Comment: @ViryaKho The last comma in values is extra. remove it and test again

Comment: Did you notice that the `insert into` statement has six column names but only five items in the `values` list? Either `, id_buku` should not be in the column names or you need to add another parameter to the `values` list. Looking at the following select statement suggests that `, id_buku` should not be there because you're comparing it against `scope_identity()`.

Comment: yea bro @SaeedEsmaeelinejad  , I just add some code to `Insert into` , I forget to put the Kategori in Values .. Thanks but it's still don't work bro

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I just add the `kategori` to `Insert into` values but it also don't work bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys , I just found the answer why error. I think the primary key can't set to identity increment when want to add some column... Is it correct?
I just set the identity increment to NO, and finally I solve the problem... :)

Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: When you set a column to be ``Identity`` means no need to add values in ``Insert Into`` statement and I think you should set Identity Increment to Yes and remove its column from insert.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Sorry bro, So what should I do? I don't really understand...

Comment: Your Insert query will be like this: ``INSERT INTO TBL_Buku  (Judul_buku, engarang, Penerbit, Tahun_terbit, Kategori) VALUES (@Judul_buku,@Pengarang,@Penerbit,@Tahun_terbit,@Kategori)``

Comment: @saeedesmaeelinejad So the code without the primary key?

Comment: Primary key is identity(if set identity increment yes) and will evaluate automatically